# Using bash to remove pattern from line in a more than 10G sql file when pattern match

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

what is the best way for me to use bash script to remove the pattern from sql file once the field 9, , on the line is older than 1 days of current time. I have try to use grep or sed to remove the line but since the file is larger than 10G, it takes more than 20 mins to clean up

```
data format:
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('data1','data2','data3',data4,'data5',data6,data7,data8,'2016-12-14 06:22:20','data10'),('data_a1','data_a2','data_a3',data_a4,'data_a5',data_a6,data_a7,data_a8,'2017-01-31 06:26:38','data_a 10'),('data_b 1','data_b 2','data_b 3',data_b 4,'data_b 5',data_b 6,data_b 7,data_b 8,'2016-12-14 06:31:16','data_b 10')
INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('Tdata1','Tdata2','Tdata3',Tdata4,'Tdata5',Tdata6,Tdata7,Tdata8,'2017-01-31 06:22:20','Tdata10'),('Tdata_a1','Tdata_a2','Tdata_a3',Tdata_a4,'Tdata_a5',Tdata_a6,Tdata_a7,Tdata_a8,'2016-01-31 08:26:38','Tdata_a 10'),('Tdata_b 1','Tdata_b 2','Tdata_b 3',Tdata_b 4,'Tdata_b 5',Tdata_b 6,Tdata_b 7,Tdata_b 8,'2017-01-31 04:31:16','Tdata_b 10')

expect result:
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('data_a1','data_a2','data_a3',data_a4,'data_a5',data_a6,data_a7,data_a8,'2017-01-31 06:26:38','data_a 10')
INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('Tdata1','Tdata2','Tdata3',Tdata4,'Tdata5',Tdata6,Tdata7,Tdata8,'2017-01-31 06:22:20','Tdata10'),('Tdata_b 1','Tdata_b 2','Tdata_b 3',Tdata_b 4,'Tdata_b 5',Tdata_b 6,Tdata_b 7,Tdata_b 8,'2017-01-31 04:31:16','Tdata_b 10')
```

Comment: Can You show us the `grep` and `sed`  attempts?

Comment: sed -i "s/^INSERT INTO \`table1\` .*.$//g" dump.sql . i only know how to remove the line once I found the insert query from table

Comment: [replace-text-quickly-in-very-large-file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255373/replace-text-quickly-in-very-large-file) .... I don't know if it works for you

Comment: Can any of the strings you've called \*data\* contain `(`, `)`, or `,`, or do they contain only alphanumeric data ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick those are http response log from a json file that contains any alphanumeric, specially character or any string

Comment: OK, so the regular expression `([^)]*)` will completely match one of the tuples (and not just part of one)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, no it does not match part of one

Comment: why not just insert into the DB and then remove the rows you don't want?

Comment: of course my original sql is about 15G, it takes about 30 mins to insert it and another 20 mins to delete useless data